# Automatic merge of an MR on GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pull-request, merge-request

I have recently stumbled upon a use-case where I want to make MRs into my `master` branch automatically. Every one of those MRs would edit a documentation file which does not in any way affect business flows or local / remote app config. I unfortunately need to make an MR to trigger a webhook that talks to a different repo, instead of just committing the documentation file to `master` directly.

The closest I have found to "automatically" is the `merge_request.merge_when_pipeline_succeeds` [push option](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html) which is available since Git 2.10. I was wondering if there is a way for me to even skip the pipeline stage as, in my case, it is useless and just wastes time. I suspect that this is *not* supported out of an abundance of caution, but it couldn't hurt to ask.

Comment: So merge them. What question do you want to ask? Here is the API https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#merge-a-merge-request . Anyway, I do not understand why make a merge request that auto merges, just push the edits to master.

Comment: I agree with @KamilCuk. If you are trying to automatically create an MR and then automatically complete it, then perhaps you can simply checkout `master`, make your commit, then push it, fast enough that you don't need to merge. You may need to adjust permissions so that the user that pushes the commit can bypass branch protection, but perhaps doing that is simpler than automating an MR.

Comment: I failed to clarify that I *need* to make an MR into `master` instead of directly pushing to it, to trigger a webhook that occurs on Merge Request events. I edited the original post to mention this, my mistake.

Comment: Fair enough. Good edit. Another thing is unclear to me: the title suggests you wish to automatically *complete* an existing MR (I assume if some condition is met...), but the first sentence suggests you want to automatically *create* an MR (I assume triggered by some process). Maybe you wish to do both? For example, perhaps you start a process which creates a branch, makes a doc change and commits it while on that branch, pushes the branch, creates an MR, then completes the MR?